# Gatsby fail to compile with flow

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, flowtype, gatsby

I have installed Flow in my Gatsby project, by adding the plugin gatsby-plugin-flow.

It has created a .flowconfig file in project root and a *"gatsby-plugin-flow": "^1.0.4"* dependency in package.json.

When I run *gatsby develop*, there is an error :

```
ERROR in ./src/components/layout.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/babel-loader.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/iqc/project/src/components/layout.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:29)

   8 | import "./layout.css"
   9 | 
> 10 | const Layout = ({ children } : Object) => (
     |                              ^
  11 |   <StaticQuery
  12 |     query={graphql`
```

It looks like Babel is failing to compile the project.
Maybe a problem with ES6 in Gatsby ?

I also tried to install Flow with official docs (no plugin), but the same problem occurs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed `gatsby-plugin-flow`, but you also need to add it as a plugin in the `gatsby-config.js` file.

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-flow'],
}
```